# Как предотвратить переименовывание классов в Webpack Angular?

Tags: css, angular2, angular, webpack

Я подключил файл стилей с описанием классов глобально в angular.
Если страницу написать целиком в одном файле, то весь дизайн работает.
Если же я создам компонент и часть данных перенесу в него и подключу его в разметке, то часть стилей теряются- вообщем дизайн плывёт.
Не понимаю- почему . Может ли быть, что webpack переименовывает классы и затем я хочу применить к элементу класс myclass - то он переименуется до другого и класс и стили не применятся?
Если да- то как быть с этим?
Если нет- то что может ещё быть, что объяснит, почему внутри компонента классы не работают, когда если вынести разметку в файл высшего уровня, где подключен глобальный файл стилей- то всё работает.

Comment: потому что там есть css loader который конкатенирует твои классы с атрибутами, поэтому изменяя классы из родительского компонента ты не можешь влиять на классы, находящие внутри дочернего компонента. Для этого используется `::ng-deep`, хотя в принципе зачем тебе это делать? :) если у тебя стили и шаблон взаимосвязаны, то тебе не нужно их выносить на глобальный уровень

Comment: @overthesanity их мне передал дизайнер в одном минимизированном файле. А другие сборки scss у меня не компилируются - выходит только использовать один общий файл по дизайну

Comment: подход так себе, но ладно, бывает. Если бы я столкнулся с такой задачей я бы поступил следующим образом - деминимизировал этот файл, далее распарсил бы этот CSS в AST дерево (например через `csstree`), для того, чтобы выделить функциональные части и повторяющиеся селекторы, например если будут 2 селектора `.parent` и `.parent button`, то можно теоретически сделать вывод, куда дальше перемещать эти стили, например в какой-то компонент где есть `div.parent`. Если же там все селекторы в разнобой, то это проблематичнее, но реально. Еще есть вариант дать дизайнеру по шапке =)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` свойство в декораторе `@Component`. Это убирает инкапсуляцию стилей с уровня компонента до глобального.

По умолчанию, Angular замыкает стили на уровень компонентов с помощью добавления сгенерированного атрибута, например: `[_nghost-abs-c10]`. Читайте [тут](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#Emulated)

Comment: это почти то, что нужно, но оно заработало, так как это на стили действует, а у меня в разметке myclass, который по-видимому переименовывается. А в главном файле у меня подключается стиль myclass, который уже не соответствует ему. Как можно настроить, что б классы в разметке не переименовывались?

Comment: Я попробовал добавить, но всё-равно стили не работают 
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
    {
        defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    }
]);

Comment: стили и классы не должны переименовываться. У вас в разметке на выходе другой класс?

Comment: классы те же, но вот странно- отображение всё-равно такое-же

Comment: так посмотрите, какие стили к ним применяются. возможно, по пути они переписываются более специфичными